# Helical Particle Waves?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, soft-question, grand-unification

[Helical Particle Waves][1]

Helical Particle Waves: http://www.heliwave.com/gaasenbeek/spap1.html

In the link above someone explains a new theory that explains the general relativity and quantum mechanics. I can't judge the idea, but what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion, don't waste your time on it. Only from this

> Not only does the helical particle wave concept explain all the characteristics of light, etc., by means of a single model, but it allows one to calculate the exact position, velocity and spin of any relativistic particle without the need for such dubious concepts as:
>
> - Einstein's time dilation and relativistic mass,
> - Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, or
> - Bohr's complimentary principle.

you can deduce that it's all hogwash. Just another crackpot.

Comment: Other than the remarks you've written, what else put you off?

Comment: At the start of the "paper" it claims that this model can explain all the "characteristics of light", but with no proof what so ever. It states that there is still a big mystery about the dual nature of particles (ignoring quantum field theory much?). It's just a bunch of formulas put together around the notion of a helical type path.

Comment: @user102148 A paper with this "look" making such claims might have cut it around 1900. But today it would need firstly to be (1) a sizeable essay reviewing all the experimental results, especially things like time dilation which is fantastically well backed up experimentally, and showing in detail what it is about these results that the proposed theory explains better. Also, I would expect anything "really explaining" both relativity and quantum mechanics would / should be put to the test in describing things where these two theories have historically sat uneasily together: ....

Comment: @user102148 .... how would the theory fare describing the foundational issues addressed in detail by Bell as to locality and counterfactual realism. (2) We're probably in an era where all the easy fruit has been taken. Modern physics has become highly mathematically complex and abstract for exactly the same reason that all of science and engineering has: complexity handling needs tools to cope with a great deal of information that one person cannot intuitively handle anymore. The Einsteins and the Schrödingers don't tend to publish one author papers like this anymore: they work in teams ...

Comment: @user102148 ...and show signs of working closely together with others in their fields. Edward Witten might be an exception, but then he could be an alien http://abstrusegoose.com/332 . Also note that the whole site has gone cold since 1998. Maybe the guy simply realized that there *were* some smart people aside from him and he'd better get collaborating!

Comment: @vnb what's the weird and interesting looking circle plot on your avatar?

Comment: It's from here, http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2012/nov/01/spooky-action-with-twisted-beams . Not in my field, but there are not so many pretty pictures from quark gluon plasma or confinement.